# (HTML5 & CSS) Issue with classes

Tags: css, html, class, path

I don't understand why my class no-support isn't updating the  element to be bold and with a red color. If I type the path

```
$tbody tr .no-support
```

it has red color but it's not bold? Can someone please explain? Here is the code at JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Sm8J8/

Answer (score 2):

You should use another font property and `!important` to rewrite `tbody td:first-child` `color` CSS property :

```
.no-support {
   font-weight: bold;
   color:red !important;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sm8J8/2/)

Comment: In general !important is not a good idea, it makes harder and harder to overwrite properties. It's always better to find a more specific selector like `tbody td.no-support`. In this case it's the reason for not being colored, `tbody td:first-child` is more specific than `.no-support`. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity